# SWIG: %interface_impl does not generate java interface (ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, swig

I have a problem while generating java wrappers for C++ code using SWIG. I have a C++ class using multiple inheritance. As Java does not support it I was going to wrap one base class as an Java interface (as it is an abstract class in C++). The following simple example shows how my C++ `header.h` looks like.

```
    class Base1 {
    public:
        virtual void method1() = 0;
    }

    class Base2 {
    public:
        void metghod2();
    }

    class Derived : public Base1, public Base2{
    public:
        virtual void method1();
    }
```

And my `input.i` file looks like this

```
    %module wrap

    %include <swiginterface.i>
    %interface_impl(Base1);

    %{
        #include "header.h"
    %}

    %include "header.h"
```

SWIG documentation says that in this case two Java wrapper files should be generated for a class Base1: `Base1.java` (containing a java interface) and `Base1SwigImpl.java` (containing java proxy class). The problem is that SWIG generates for me only the second file and there is no java interface file (`Base1.java`). There is also a SWIG warning:

> Warning 813: Warning for Derived proxy: Base Base1 ignored. Multiple inheritance is not supported in Java.

The problem only occurs on ubuntu. When I wrap it on Windows everything works fine. On Windows I have SWIG 3.0.10 on ubuntu SWIG 3.0.8

After installing SWIG on ubuntu there was no `swiginterface.i` file and I got an error that this file was not found. But I copied the file to the place where all `.i` file was and now SWIG sees it but steel don't work properly as I explained it above.

I run swig from console with command:

```
swig -c++ -java -package pcg input.i
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

thanx for any help.

Comment: I can't remember exactly when this was introduced, but `%interface_impl` was only added very recently so I'd be willing to bet it's simply not properly implemented in 3.0.8.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Upgrading SWIG on ubuntu to 3.0.10 helped. Shame on me. I also found a compatibility note about it in SWIG docmentation, but I closed the docs and now can't find it again... thanks for help